# Typescript: incorrect type for object spread operator?

Tags: typescript

Consider this code snippet:

```
type Foo = {
  x: string;
  y: number;
};

let a: Foo = {
  x: "@",
  y: 3,
};

let b: Partial<Foo> = { x: "#", y: undefined };

let c = { ...a, ...b };
```

Clearly type of `c` cannot be `Foo` because property `y` is `undefined`: runtime value of `c` is `{x: "#", y: undefined}` (at least in Chrome). Yet Typescript infers `c` type as `{ x: string; y: number;}`. You can check in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play for  version 4.0.5. I'm confused.

EDIT: here is the link from the comments to the github issue with the exact same problem https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195#issuecomment-373178677 . For now this is the answer.

Comment: Please take a look here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195 
Also, AFAIK, spread operator is not very well typed in TS

Comment: TS just does the same as JS: if you indicate a prop explicitly it sure exists in an object even with `undefined` value. To make sure you need to call `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @captain-yossarian you should make that an answer (maybe referencing [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195#issuecomment-373178677)); the compiler does not consistently understand the difference between "present-but-`undefined`" and "missing".  The spread operator seems to assume that an `undefined` optional property is missing and will not overwrite previously set properties. This assumption is probably correct most of the time, but not in the example here.  Note you use a required property and not an optional one, [the issue goes away](https://tsplay.dev/KWzdEN).

Comment: @jcalz I can't it  make an answer because I learnt it from your anwers and comments. Your answer will be a way better than mine)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue there is the type `Partial<Foo>`:

```
let b: Partial<Foo> = { x: "#", y: undefined };
```

When you specify the variable type, the ts compiler usually ignores the right side of the assignment and doesn't use it for type inference (there are some exceptions, but in general it works this way).

Comment: Do not see any problem. `{ x: "#", y: undefined }` is a valid value for a set defined by type `Partial<Foo>`. So TS is right not complaining. On the contrary TS is rightfully upset if I write
`let b: Foo = { x: "#", y: undefined };`

Comment: Just to clarify: "the ts compiler usually ignores the right side " means that the expression type is not used for type narrowing e.g. after the declaration the effective type of the variable is still ``Partial<Foo>``,  not ``{x: string; y: undefined}``. There is also an issue with the compiler that it doesn't produce an optional flag for the result spread type, but I believe it is a compiler bug

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use [--exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types).

### Details

This *was* a known issue with the TypeScript compiler: it did not properly distinguish between missing properties vs set-to-undefined properties.

See: [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).

Since Typescript 4.4 ([released in August 2021](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/)), there is a new compiler flag called [--exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types). The flag was introduced exactly to solve this problem and properly distinguish between missing and undefined properties.

So the solution is to enable the flag.

The TS team even announced that [it will become the default](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44421#issuecomment-858870879) for new projects initialized with `tsc --init`.

However, as of September 2022, it still seems like the ecosystem is not completely ready for the new flag to be enabled in every project -- because a lot of existing libraries (including some React components) still declaring partial objects the old way, which brings significant inconveniences, if the flag is enabled.